# Using @Input property in Angular 2

Tags: angular

Below is my sample Angular 2 component code

```
@Component({
selector: 'author-edit',
templateUrl:'./author/edit'

})

export class AuthorEditComponent implements OnInit{

    @Input() author: AuthorModel;
    fg: FormGroup;

    constructor(
        public formBuilder: FormBuilder

    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
       alert(this.author.id); // ERROR Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

    }

    }
}
```

This component is used from parent component in below mentioned way

```
<author-edit [author]="editAuthor"></author-edit>
```

In the above code, why is that I am unable to access this.author.id value of "author" input property.

Comment: what is editAuthor exactly?

Comment: `editAuthor` is not set in parent scope

Comment: it is an object of type "AuthorModel"

Comment: By your provided example we will not be able to determine issue

Comment: just test your component and it's working well. So I assume something is wrong around editAuthor. Are you sure AuthorModel and it instance contains a id?

Comment: your have a extra  "}" in your code. Are you sure is not that?

Comment: Its not due to the extra "}" , that was typo , in fact I am able to access the value in my template like this [value]="author?.first_name"

Comment: and author?.id is working?

Comment: yes.. it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to detect passing @Input() argument, use OnChange abstract class instead of OnInit in this way:

```
export class AuthorEditComponent implements OnChanges{

    @Input() author: AuthorModel;
    fg: FormGroup;

    constructor(
        public formBuilder: FormBuilder

    ) {}

    ngOnChanges(changes:{[propName: string]: SimpleChange}): any {
        if(changes['author'] && this.author) {
            alert(this.author.id);
        }
    }
}
```

You can't be sure that @Input() value was passed in the moment when ngOnInit was called